# Apple App Re-Submission doesn't ask again about 3rd party content. Why?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, app-store

When submitting an app you are asked "Does your app contain, display or access third-party content?". I mistakenly chose yes the first time around. I should have chosen no. I'm attempting to re-submit after rejection, but am only being asked about "export compliance" and "advertising identifier". It is not asking about 3rd party content again.

How can I submit so that it will ask me again, and I can choose no?

Is it ok to just create a new app in iTunes Connect, and do it all through a brand new app? Or would you not be able to reclaim the same name, because it would be taken by your original app? If you change the app name in your original app, will you be able to use it on this newly created iTunes connect app?

Comment: Was the rejection to do with third-party content?

Comment: @user523234 yes because I didn't provide auth. However I'm not using any 3rd party content and therefore cannot provide auth. Under the advice of my lawyer I'm not using 3rd party content. I mistakenly thought I was. Now I need to undo that.